# What rights are needed for 64-bit debugging on Windows?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-12-athens

What rights are needed for 64-bit debugging on Windows?

That is the short, difficult question.

An answer that makes it work using either Delphi 11.3 or Delphi 12 is what I'm looking for. (Am currently using 11.3, but could upgrade to 12 if that helps make 64-bit debugging work.)

##### What I know so far

I use a trivial VCL application for testing. It contains a form with a button and this event handler (that's all):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := 5;
  x := x * x;
  Caption := IntToStr(x);
end;
```

If Delphi is **"Run as Administrator"**, then 64-bit debugging works.

When Delphi is run **normally**, that is, **not "as Administrator"** (and, interestingly, even when my current Windows user *does* belong to the local Administrators group), then debugging never starts visibly, except for that windows are arranged according to the Debug Layout. It never says "Running" in the Delphi IDE window's title.

**Task Manager** shows the participating processes running, including my program being debugged, but the program never shows up visibly, and the Delphi IDE shows no signs of having entered any debugging state.

[image: Task Manager view]

However, if I try to close the Delphi project in this state, it seems aware that it's debugging, because it complains **"This current debug session must end before the requested operation can complete."** After I click Terminate, it says **"Debugger fatal error during process reset: 'Debug process is already running'. Please save your work and restart Delphi 11."** (In Delphi 12, it says the same but with a 12 at the end.)

Our company (IT policy) does not allow me to run as Administrator (except on specific request, but not on a daily basis). According to Embarcadero support, Admin rights are not required, but they have also not been able to provide a list of precise requirements. They have a helpful and friendly attitude, but seem to be searching for the answer themselves, is my impression.

**'Debug programs' right**

Giving my user the "Debug programs" right, which seems reasonable, has not made any visible difference.

**Firewall**

The debugger process needs to be let through the firewall (because 64-bit debugging is technically a remote debugging, also locally, because the Delphi IDE is a 32-bit application), but I think that that is in place and correct already, because if the firewall were the problem, then I presume running as administrator would not make any difference. The firewall behaves the same regardless of which user I am running as, doesn't it?

**Controlled Folders**

Adding `$(BDS)\bin\dbkw64_28_0.exe` to the "allowed apps" list for Controlled Folders in Windows also seems to make no difference.

**Antivirus**

Our antivirus software shows no signs of having blocked anything, neither with popup messages nor in logs, so it does not seem to be the problem (but my gut feeling has not ruled that out completely). I cannot turn off antivirus software even momentarily, unfortunately, so I cannot test this myself.

**Reliability history**

The "View reliability history" report in Windows does not show anything abnormal related to the debugger or to the times when I've tried to use the debugger.

**Observation by Embarcadero support**

This observation by Embarcadero support, comparing their debug log (top) with mine (bottom) and noting a significant difference, is interesting, but what do with it? The "why" is a mystery.

This is from a DBK log on my system, you can see debugger is calling `CreateProcessW` (with DEBUG flags), the debugging thread then gets notified that the debugging session has start with this `CREATE_PROCESS_EVENT`

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[8680: 51565 ] CreateProcessW RC 1 osPid 2936 [CL=00000000]
[8680: 51565 ] setOSProcId(DbkProcId_t 1) -> 2936 0xb78 [CL=00000000]
[8680: 51565 ] leave:] W64PCntrlSrv::dispatch(START_PROC-1) [CL=00000200]
[8680: 51565 ] leave:] waitForCmdOrEvent [CL=00000200]
[7336: 51565 ] XX readn ->1312 [CL=00000000]
[8680: 51565 ] [start: waitForCmdOrEvent [CL=00000200]
[7336: 51565 ] leave:] doCmd(START_PROC-1) [CL=00000200]
[7336: 51565 ] leave:] cmdStartProc C:\Work\SalesForce\1021668\Win64\Debug\Project2.exe launch (null) cwd C:\Work\SalesForce\1021668\Win64\Debug\ [CL=00000200]
[8680: 51565 ] eventWait new Ev code 0000000000000003 [CL=00000000]
[7336: 51565 ] W64Proc::init() -> 1 [CL=00000000]
[8680: 51565 ] queing CREATE_PROCESS_EVENT(3) pId 2936 tId 7296 [CL=00000000]
[7336: 51565 ] leave:] W64Proc::init path "C:\Work\SalesForce\1021668\Win64\Debug\Project2.exe" args "" launcherPath (null) [CL=00000200]
[8680: 51565 ] [start: findThreadByOSTid( 7296 ) [CL=00000200]
[7336: 51565 ] <-API] IDbk::createProcess [CL=00000220]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now in your DBK log

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[5768: 7022 ] CreateProcessW RC 1 osPid 18444 [CL=00000000]
[5768: 7022 ] setOSProcId(DbkProcId_t 1) -> 18444 0x480c [CL=00000000]
[5768: 7022 ] leave:] W64PCntrlSrv::dispatch(START_PROC-1) [CL=00000200]
[5768: 7022 ] leave:] waitForCmdOrEvent [CL=00000200]
[5768: 7022 ] [start: waitForCmdOrEvent [CL=00000200]
[12780: 7022 ] XX readn ->1312 [CL=00000000]
[12780: 7022 ] leave:] doCmd(START_PROC-1) [CL=00000200]
[5768: 7022 ] eventWait new Ev code 0000000000000001 [CL=00000000]
[12780: 7022 ] leave:] cmdStartProc C:\Users\matthias.AARO\OneDrive - AARO Systems AB\Dokument\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\64-bit debug test\Win64\Debug\Test64bit.exe launch (null) cwd C:\Users\matthias.AARO\OneDrive - AARO Systems AB\Dokument\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\64-bi [CL=00000200]
[5768: 7022 ] cmd incoming [CL=00000000]
[12780: 7022 ] W64Proc::init() -> 1 [CL=00000000]
[5768: 7022 ] [start: W64PCntrlSrv::readCmd [CL=00000200]
[12780: 7022 ] leave:] W64Proc::init path "C:\Users\matthias.AARO\OneDrive - AARO Systems AB\Dokument\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\64-bit debug test\Win64\Debug\Test64bit.exe" args "" launcherPath (null) [CL=00000200]
[12780: 7022 ] <-API] IDbk::createProcess [CL=00000220] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As you can see debugger does not see the normal `CREATE_PROCESS_EVENT` being fired by OS at all? So something is preventing the OS from generating the notification. It looks like debugee is launched but the debugger does not know it.

Comment: I've never needed to run as administrator to get 64 but debugging to work. But even when it works you'll never manage more than a few breakpoints before it gives up.

Comment: So what could be the difference? My colleague and I see this behaviour, both of us on two different computers. We don't see any computer behaving in any other way. Without running as administrator, debugging does not even start for us. CORRECTION: In a virtual machine of ours, debugging works also without running as admin. But on all domain-enrolled computers, it fails.

Comment: I think you need to ask your IT department.

Comment: You should contact Embarcadero Support. 64bit debugging has been problematic for awhile.

Comment: Some tools like SysInternals Process Monitor can be used to see what it was trying to do when it was blocked (needs admin privileges however).

Comment: I have asked my IT department and also been in pretty long contact with Embarcadero support. None of them has had any clear answers, but are trying this and that. We keep trying. I'm fishing for any ideas or advice, and of course ultimately the answer to what exactly is needed to make it work.

Comment: I added to the post an observation by Embarcadero support about CREATE_PROCESS_EVENT.

Comment: I would suggest not using OneDrive for development directories.

Comment: @Brian Indeed, true. The problem remains the same, though, also when only simple local folders are used.

Comment: @MatthiasB You say that the problem occurs on all domain-enrolled computers not not inside Virtual machine. This would indicate that your domain-entrolled computers probably have stronger security settings which might be interfering with Delphi. I recommend you and your IT guys try to set similar security settings to the windows installation inside WM one by one in order to track down which security settings might be causing the problem.